# How to publish Twist messages cmd_vel to turtlebot on ROS?

Tags: python-2.7, ros

this question mainly comes due to my lack of understanding of the ROS and inability to find exactly the topic.

For turtlesim, the topic is **turtle1/cmd_vel** to publish command velocity messages to
For turtlebot3, what is the topic to publish cmd_vel messages to?

I have done something like this for turtlesim

```py
command_topic_velocity = '/turtle1/cmd_vel'
publisher_velocity = rospy.Publisher(command_topic_velocity, Twist, queue_size=10)
```

what would `command_topic_velocity` be for **Turtlebot3 on ROS melodic**?

Answer (score 0):

you shoud use cmd_vel

```
 pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
```

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_teleop/nodes/turtlebot3_teleop_key

and you can use rostopic nameoftopic show